# calling frame on UIView gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

This is a weird behavior that I just can't understand:

I access my own subclassed UIViews like this:

```
    UIView *aZettel = [self.view viewWithTag:100]; 
    NSLog(@"aZettel %@", aZettel);
```

The view I'm calling is my own class, it's an UIView containing one UIImageView and one UILabel. NSLog shows:

```
    2011-10-04 09:45:35.969 accessapp[11264:207] aZettel <Zettel: 0x534b1c0; frame = (88 103; 160 106); tag = 100; layer = <CALayer: 0x534abc0>>
```

but when I write NSLog(@"aZettel %@", aZettel.frame); the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line with NSLog. Zombies says nothing.

I wouldn't ask if I hadn't already wasted almost one day with this. The longer I try stuff with trial and error the more confused I get. Anybody a hint what could be causing this?

Comment: you set tag 100 to view or any other like your imageview or lable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program crashes because in

```
NSLog(@"aZettel %@", aZettel.frame);
```

NSLog expects its parameter to be valid object, while you pass c-struct to it (CGRect). Convert CGRect to NSString to log it:

```
NSLog(@"aZettel %@", NSStringFromCGRect(aZettel.frame));
```

Comment: Thanks, there's a million things to learn in Objective-C. It's like you have to do befriend the butcher on get to know him on a very personal level, get to know every aspect of his life ... when all you want is to buy a steak.